# How to write this simple javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some nav links like so:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</ul>
```

How can I add a CSS class called `active` to the opening `<li>` tag of the list item that contains the `a href` whose value matches the current url?

For example, if the current page the user is on is `about.html` then the nav should look like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</ul>
```

Please note:

the urls can have additional parameters like:

about.html?foo=bar&bar=loo

so whatever is used to detect the url should not take parameters into consideration but just the page name and extensions.

I would prefer to achieve this in plain JavaScipt since I am not using jQuery for anything else on the site, but either is fine.

### Edit

The index page had index.html in the url when it's landed on from another page but if the domain is types it shows as:

```
http://www.sitename.com/
```

so if no page is specified the active class should be attached to the home list's tag.

Comment: you want to do it for cosmetic reasons or for functionality? because if you are adding that class for styling, you have CSS pseudo class :active

Comment: Ok, I added the changes. Next time please post all issues at once...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery:

```
if(window.location.pathname === '') {
     $('#nav li:first-child').addClass('active');
}
else {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    $('#nav li').filter(function(index) {            
        return path === $(this).children('a').attr('href');
    }).addClass('active');
}
```

Plain JavaScript:

```
var menu_elements = document.getElementById('nav').children;
if(window.location.pathname === '') {
     menu_elements[0].className += ' active';
}
else {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    for(var i = menu_elements.length; i--;) {
        var element = menu_elements[i];
        var a = element.children[0];
        if(a.href === path) {
            element.className += ' active';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: [`children[]` is not supported by FF 3.0](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71). If you experience any problems with `children`, you can substitute this with an appropriate `getElementsByTagName` call.*

Comment: @mplungjan: No, why should you? It uses different methods and might be a bit more compatible...

Answer (score 1):

Simple version

```
window.onload=function() {
  var activeLi;
  if (location.pathname) { 
    var fileName = location.pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexof('/')+1);
  /* just take the start - 
     not handling filenames that are substrings of other filenames 
     nor filenames with more than one dot. */
    fileName = fileName.split('.')[0]; 
    var links = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
      if (links[i].href.indexOf(fileName)==0) { // starts with filename
        activeLi = links[i].parentNode;
        break; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { // no page given
    activeLi = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
  }
  if (activeLi) activeLi.className="active";
}
```

More complex would be to ADD the active to className, but if you do not have other classes on the LI, then it is not needed - but if you use jQuery it is much simpler.

Comment: +1 I would remove the loop over the `a` elements as it can be assumed that each list element only contains one link. But you have some flaws: If the URL is like `.../contact.php#foo/bar` then you approach does not work anymore and it should be `indexOf(fileName)`.

Comment: I drop everything after .html - if it changes to php or might change then I can drop whatever is after the dot - fixed as such (as well as the 'fileName', thanks. I loop over the a since that is what I can test against. Otherwise I will have to go for li[x].getElementsByTagName('a')[0] or childnodes/childnodes which can be a textnode in non-IE - hohum, so can the parentNode so yeah

Comment: @mplungjan: Ah sorry, right, you loop over all `a` in the list not over them in each list item. I missed that. And sorry, my example was badly chosen, I did not mean a different file ending, but when a slash appears anywhere after the filename (`#foo/bar`).

Comment: Ah, yes. that would be unhandy :) But so do you by the way:   
`path = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

Comment: @mplungjan: But I only take the path of the URL, excluding the query and the hash...

Comment: Oups. my bad. thought .search and .hash also was in the pathname... oh well. At least I use substring and not substr ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get sub-domain url 
var currentUrl = window.location.href,
    splitUrlArr = currentUrl.replace(/\?.*/,'').split('\/');
    subDomainUrl = splitUrlArr[splitUrlArr.length-1];
//if url matches the site home url, add classname 'active' to first li
if(splitUrlArr.join('\/') == currentUrl) {
    document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('li')[0].className = "active";
}else {
    //Find the matching href and add className 'active' to its parent li
    var targetLi = null;
    var links = document.getElementById('nav').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href === subDomainUrl) { 
            targetLi = links[i].parentNode;
            break; 
        }
    }
    if(targetLi) { targetLi.className = "active"; }
}
```